# F# Type Providers very very slow build

Tags: .net, f#, type-providers

I'm playing around with Type Providers, specifically the sql entity framework type provider.
I'm writing tests against a database that has a LOT of objects, and it's remote so the connection is a little slow. every time i build the project it takes a lot of time, good several minutes for the build to complete.

what am I missing why does the compiler doesn't cache the type information?

P.S.
It's even worse with F# interactive....

Comment: What are you benchmarking against that you consider this is slow? What's your point of comparison? I mean, have you tried the Type Providers against a different back end? Vote to close because this is an overly-broad question.

Comment: A build that takes several minutes every time takes too long... im comparing to every other build.

Comment: A build that takes several minutes every time?  I used to work on a commercial C++ app that took 1/2 hour to build every time we built it--and that was after several rounds of optimization.  Unless you're building toy code every time, compilation is going to take some time. Saying "it's too slow" is sort of like an end-user saying "it's too hard to use"--vague and pretty useless.

Comment: i have one source file, and it contains 9 lines. the compiler reconstructs the entire "magic" behind the type provider, every time I compile and it indeed takes too long.

Comment: Good question, may be some people never heard of tdd? and still go around feeding punch cards to their computer;-) Quick builds and being able to run quick test rounds is very very important!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the LocalSchemaFile attribute for the data provider. This points to a .csdl file that is used to generate the types. You can have the type provider update this file by setting the ForceUpdate attribute to true. To run from a cached schema simply set ForceUpdate to false. Here is how I do this with the SqlDataConnection provider, which is very similar to the SqlEntityConnection provider.

```
type schema = SqlDataConnection< LocalSchemaFile = "Schema.dbml", ForceUpdate = false, ConnectionString = @"Data Source=<insert your connection string here>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides what can be defined as a 'slow build', (if you are in the red green tdd development circle, builds quickly become slow!), I moved my client type provider code to a separate project. I already had ForceUpdate set to false, but still builds were slow (apparently still some background checking of the generated dbml files was going on, in my case wsdlschema files actually).

After moving all the type provider code to a separate projects, builds were significantly faster!

Note: loading the interactive was even more quick, only you have to add the reference to the dll for the types

Answer (score 0):

Seems like bottleneck is in remote connection. I also assume you have to edit and recmpile db access code frequently.

Some type providers can point to local SQL scripts instead of live connection, if it's not the case then make a local db which will replicate the schema (and static data in 'enum' tables if you have any). Connection for type providers/compiler and for runtime doesn't have to be the same.

There are tools to sync schemas once in a while e.g.Red Gate SQL Compare (this is one is great but not free), or simply regenerate full db schema SQL and recreate local database and run it once in a while (this also can be automated but it's a different story).